# MOSFET: how to determine if a heatsink is required?

Tags: mosfet, heatsink, power-dissipation

for a given mosfet, how do I know how much current can it handle without a heatsink?

I could just play it safe and add a heatsink + fan but the controller board am using doesn't have mounting holes for any pcb mount heatsink. It is fused but I just want to be sure.

So for example  If I was using a mosfet as a switch for a 360w load and it's 0.31 degree c per watt then in 25degrees c air it'll be

0.31 x 360w = 111 degrees c!!!! based on a IXFH52N30P as a example

If for example I was stupid enough to not use a heatsink then it could termally runaway due to the mosfet rasing the amient temperature right?

Comment: You look up the thermal specifications in the datasheet

Comment: so it will say I have absolute maxium power of 200w and I shouldn't go anywhere near it

Comment: It is not the current, but it is the **power dissipation** what is relevant here. Current times voltage drop equals power. Then use the thermal specifications to calculate the resulting temperature rise.

Comment: *I have absolute maxium power of 200w* That is not a **thermal specification**, that is a **safe operating area specification**. A thermal spec is like: Thermal resistance of Junction to Case: 3.5 K/W. Free air operation: 80 C/W. The Kelvin/Watt or Celsius/Watt numbers is what you need. So 80 K/W means that in 20 degrees C air, MOSFET dissipating 1 Watt, it will reach 20 + 80 = 100 degrees Celsius, that's HOT !

Comment: Answers would be more relevant if you told us what this mosfet is used for. To simply switch on/off something? As the output stage of a class D amp? Of a class A amp? What are the current/voltages involved? What is the part number of this mosfet? (any datasheet?)

Comment: Sorry just a switch. It's switch on and off a heated bed for a 3d printer.  Trouble is i don't know exactly how much current my particular 3d printer bed uses and I have not brought a controller yet. Just as an example lets say it's switching a 400w load. what mosfet do you recommend

Comment: @Ageis No, you are under constraining the question by saying the load is 400 watts. Define precisely what the supply voltage is and what current the load takes then state what gate drive voltage you are using then take a stab at the MOSFET you think will work and show how you have put that MOSFET into the circuit. Then someone might feel the urge to answer.

Comment: You are confusing the power in the load with the power in the transistor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The power consumption of the *load* is completely irrelevant. The 400W power you're switching is not dissipated by the MOSFET. It is, by definition, dissipated by the load. The MOSFET dissipates much less power (hopefully).

In a switching (on/off) application, here is how it works:

- Calculate the drain current I<sub>D</sub> that will go through the MOSFET. You can determine it by dividing your load power consumption (400W) by the load voltage (you didn't specify it). Or maybe it's directly given in the load specifications.
- Check the gate voltage you'll drive the mosfet with. It depends on your controller board, so it should be specified in its documentation. It usually is from 5V to 12V. Maybe it depends on the voltage you're supplying to the controller board.
- Check the datasheet of the MOSFET to get the V<sub>DS</sub> at the gate voltage and drain current you're using. In the IXFH52N30P datasheet, it is given in figure 3 (assuming 125°C - fig.1 is for 25°C, but we most likely be much hotter than this). For example, with a 10V gate voltage and 20A, it is about 2.5V.
- The power *the MOSFET* (not the load) will dissipate is: V<sub>DS</sub> * I<sub>D</sub>. With the assumptions above, it makes about 50W (2.5V * 20A).
- To check if you can go without heatsink, you would then get the R<sub>thJA</sub> (junction to ambient) thermal resistance value given in the datasheet (given in °C/W) and multiply it by the power dissipated. For the IXFH52N30P, *R<sub>thJA</sub> is not given in the datasheet*. It seems the engineers here assumed that the FET would only be used with a heatsink. Anyway, these kind of FET packages can't handle much more than a few watts without heatsink, and I guess you'll be above.
- So, now, assuming you need a heastink, get the heatsink thermal resistance by applying this formula: (T<sub>JM</sub> - T<sub>A</sub>) / P - R<sub>thJC</sub> - R<sub>thCS</sub>. Basically, you compute the max total thermal resistance by dividing the temperature difference between "max junction temp" (150°C - given in datasheet) and ambient temp by the power. Then you subtract the junction-case and case-sink thermal resistances (both given in datasheet too) from the value obtained.
- Choose a heatsink with a thermal resistance lower than this. The heatsinks thermal resistances should be given in their respective datasheets too (yes, even heatsinks have datasheets).

Comment: You just overlooked MOS rds(on) has a rather high positive temperature coefficient. At 100C it's ballparked to be around twice as much as at 20C. This cannot really be left behind

Comment: @carloc. You're right. But this is easy to fix, however: look at fig.3 of the datasheet (Vds at 125°C) rather than fig. 1, as I mentioned. I'm fixing my answer. Thanks. (EDIT: done).

Answer (score 7):

> how do I know how much current can it handle without a heatsink?

By looking in the datasheet and then doing the math.  This really should be obvious.

Any competent datasheet tells you the thermal resistance from die to case, and the maximum allowed die temperature.  From this you compute how much hotter the die will be than the case for a particular power dissipation.  There is nothing you can do about that part.  Subtract this from the maximum allowed die temperature, and that's the maximum temperature you can allow the case to get to.  The difference between that and the highest ambient temperature the device needs to work in is the max temperature the heatsink can drop.  Now you find a heatsink that has a thermal resistance to ambient of less than that.

Again, this is just straight forward arithmetic.

### Example

I just grabbed a random power transistor datasheet, which happened to be for a TIP42 PNP transistor.  On the first page in the absolute maximum section, it says the maximum junction temperature is 150 °C, and the maximum dissipation with the case at 25 °C is 65 W.  It doesn't tell you outright, but it implies that the junction temp is 150 °C with the case at 25 °C and dissipation of 65 W.  That means the thermal resistance from junction to case is (125 °C)/(65 W) = 1.92 °C/W.

Let's say your worst case dissipation will be 35 W and the highest ambient temperature it needs to run in is 30 °C.

At 35 W, the junction will be 67.3 °C above the case temperature.  The junction must stay at 150 °C or below, so the case must stay at 82.7 °C or below.  That leaves 52.7 °C headroom above worst case ambient.  The heatsink therefore can't allow more than 52.7 °C rise from case to ambient with 35 W thru it, or 1.51 °C/W.

So the answer in this case is you need a heatsink that can do 1.5 °C/W or less.  Note that this assumes the open end of the heatsink is at ambient.  If it is in a box, then you have to take the temperature rise in the box into account.  Also look carefully at the heatsink datasheet.  It probably assumes some minimum air flow due to convection.  It will also have considerably lower thermal resistance with forced air cooling (in other words, a fan).

Comment: I am downvoting because there is no mention to RthJA, which should be used when no heatsink is attached to the transistor. This answer also neglects RthCS, although it is highly dependent on the thermal grease applied.